# Iterate Set in order Play Framework

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0

I pass my template a `TreeSet` with `Strings`. However, when I loop over the set like this:

```
@(usernames : TreeSet[String])
@for( name <- usernames){
    @name ,
}
```

However, the names are never printed in the correct order.

How can I iterate over my set in my template and print the names in order?

Comment: What is the "correct" order? If you are expecting anything other than "alphabetical", then you should reconsider your choice of data structure for `usernames`.

Comment: @Dylan, i mean to print them alphabetically, the problem is there seems to be no ordering at all currently. One time it prints them in order, the next time i refresh the page it shows them in a different order, etc. etc.

Comment: I opened a bug on this issue in the Play issue tracker a couple of months ago. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1091

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has something to do with the way Scala Templates work. I suspect your TreeSet collection is under the hood mapped to a different collection and as a result the ordering is not preserved.

There is clearly a difference between the behavior of the Scala for loop and the for loop in Scala Templates. If you run your code as regular Scala code the order of the TreeSet is obviously preserved:

```
val users = TreeSet("foo", "bar", "zzz", "abc")    
for (user <- users) {
  println(user)
}
```

One of the ways to solve the problem is to use the iterator in the Scala Template:

```
@for(name <- usernames.iterator) {
  @name ,
}
```

or transform the TreeSet to a sequence:

```
@for(name <- usernames.toSeq) {
  @name ,
}
```

Comment: I transformed the `TreeSet` to a sequence and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed ordering for any Set class, so it's best to sort it before iterating.

If you mean to print them alphabetically, you should convert it into a List and then iterate

```
@(usernames : TreeSet[String])
@for( name <- usernames.toList().sortWith(_ < _)){
    @name ,
}
```